How to generate the h323 protocol capture packet?
Recently I am doing some research on the protocol of h323. I need to find some packets on the net but plenty of packets are not found. Such as 'Admission Reject','Location Request', 'InfoRequest' and so on. I found a source code named 'h323plus'. After read the source code I found that there was difficult to use. I would like to find the H323 packet and look at these types of packets. But some types of the h323 packets is hard to find. I am searching for a long time on net. But no use. Please help or try to give some ideas how to achieve this.Thanks in advance.
Can you give me some advise on how to generate the h323 packets? I wish that the enviorment of generate packets is not hard to build.
